# Photo Editing Mobile App for IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, loading

We are trying to build a photo app for a client where large photos are required to be fetched using a web service. These photos will be high resolution JPGs ranging in size (between roughly 5 - 7 mb).

The issue we're facing is how to fetch a batch of photos (say 10-15), store them locally on the app, and allow the user to perform editing tasks on them. What I understood from my team is if we edit the high resolution photos it will crash the app due to memory. This means we will have to reduce the resolution and size of the photo, which is reasonable, but could take a while. What is the best practice to download and reduce the photos so a good user experience is maintained?

To give some background, we are build the app for both Android and IOS. The features expected are typical swipe, pinch, editing with basic editing and advance editing like frames, text overlay, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is a UX question so much as about app architecture. 
Maybe better suited to StackOverflow or another stack exchange site instead, but I'll try to approach it from a UX angle...

**USER EXPECTATIONS**

- Do your users expect to edit high-res & have control over maintaining maximum quality? Or are they casual users just interested in making funny pix & won't care about loss of quality?

  - If they expect to have control, you could check disc space or device capability before downloading & offer them a choice of smaller size vs. slower response time.

    - For example, if they're on an older non-retina/low-pixel-density device, display an alert that editing high-res images might be difficult & offer a smaller version as an alternative.
  - How will saving/uploading edited versions work? Users might be upset if they overwrite originals w/lower quality versions & weren't given an option to "save as" or set quality level.

**USE CASES & DEVICE SPECIFICS**

- Assumption: A user on a mobile device will only work on 1 image (maybe 2) at a time.

  - No mobile device is large enough to show multiple high-res images on screen at once anyway. Keep current image in memory; only show thumbnails of others (saved on disc) until requested for editing & then swap; release/reload resources as necessary.
- If your users are using older hardware (pre-retina iPhone 3GS or iPad 2 for example), then a 5-7MB image (anything >3000px per side) might be a bit slow, but newer devices take/handle 8-12MP pictures themselves. Should be well within the device's capability to open/edit one at a time.

  - Are you saying this is not the case?? Can't even open 1 image? Is it being saved to disc first, or opened in-app directly from web service?
- Verify adequate storage space either for the whole batch beforehand, or as each image is saved

  - If device storage is full, cancel remaining downloads & alert user which images are missing

**USABILITY & RESPONSIVENESS**

- Download the images asynchronously to avoid blocking the UI
- Create much smaller low-res thumbnails to act as a placeholder for the high-res versions. Download & show thumbnails first to give a sense of progress, but differentiate between an image that's still loading & one that's available for editing (with a progress bar, transparency, etc).
- Download in the background (as you might an "in-app purchase") and save to disc.

  - Download individually & save to shared location. This keeps them organized as a batch of 10-15, but lets the user start working as soon a the 1st image is available. Don't make them wait for all of them.
  - Could use a separate "downloads" view w/progress bars & let user continue work in another tab/view
- Only once the user selects a thumbnail do you need to worry about loading/displaying the large version from disc. You can release thumbnail/loading view from memory & free up resources if necessary while the large image is being edited. Reload only as necessary.
- Auto-save to disc in background to prevent loss of work & take opportunity to clean up caches & whatnot.
- If working memory is already a concern, you won't have many options for undo/redo. Most image-editing apps manage this ok though, so there's a way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, it helped. I will check on Stack-overflow also.